# Changing multiple variables with if-statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I just started learning Javascript. For a beginners project I'm making a quiz-guide to find out which South Park character you are. But I have some problems making it work. Here are some pieces of my code:

In my HTML-document the code looks like this:

---

```
<form name="characterform">
                <p>What kind of food do you like to eat?</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="1" value="" id="radio11" />Pizza</li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="1" value="" id="radio12" />Chips and snacks</li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="1" value="" id="radio13" />Health foods</li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="1" value="" id="radio14" />Kosher</li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="1" value="" id="radio15" />Powdered donut pancake surprise</li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="1" value="" id="radio16" />Anything, as long as it's cheap</li>                   
                </ul>
                <input type="button" name="button" value="Calculate" id="button" onClick="start()" />
            </form>
```

In my script-document I begin by creating my variables and use if-statements to change them, like this:

```
function start(){
if(document.characterform.radio11.checked)
    cartman += 5;
    kyle += 5;
    stan += 5;
    kenny += 5;
    butters += 5;
```

Finally I use if-statements to get a result:

```
if(cartman > kyle && cartman > stan && cartman > kenny && cartman > butters)
    alert("Cartman! " + "\n" + cartman + "\n" + kyle + "\n" + stan + "\n" + kenny + "\n" + butters);
else if(kyle > cartman && kyle > stan && kyle > kenny && kyle > butters)
    alert("Kyle! " + "\n" + cartman + "\n" + kyle + "\n" + stan + "\n" + kenny + "\n" + butters);
else if(stan > cartman && stan > kyle && stan > kenny && stan > butters)
    alert("Stan! " + "\n" + cartman + "\n" + kyle + "\n" + stan + "\n" + kenny + "\n" + butters);
else if(kenny > cartman && kenny > stan && kenny > kyle && kenny > butters)
    alert("Kenny! " + "\n" + cartman + "\n" + kyle + "\n" + stan + "\n" + kenny + "\n" + butters);
else
    alert("Error");
```

I've done this with all my radio-buttons. The problem is that no matter which radio button is selected, the result is always the same: kyle. In fact, when looking at the print-out of the numbers it seems that Cartman is the only variable that changes. The other four variales are exactly the same, no matter what, with kyle getting the most points.

All of the script-code is in the start() function, except the creating of the variables.

I've searched alot for an answer, but I haven't found anyone with the same problem - so I'm guessing there's an easy solution to my problem. I hope someone here can help me understand this.

Comment: use brackets `(cartman > kyle)...`

Comment: Those are parentheses, and they're for grouping statements. That shouldn't be necessary  here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using multiple lines in a javascript if block, use ...

```
if(document.getElementById('radio11').checked) {
    cartman += 5;
    kyle += 5;
    stan += 5;
    kenny += 5;
    butters += 5;
}
```

Note the braces ... `{}`

You might also want to make this modification ...

```
if((cartman > kyle) && (cartman > stan) && (cartman > kenny) && (cartman > butters))
    alert("Cartman! " + "\n" + cartman + "\n" + kyle + "\n" + stan + "\n" + kenny + "\n" + butters);
...
```

... this will ensure that the comparisons are executed properly

Comment: Adding the braces did the trick! Thank you so much. I will try to implement all the other answers I got

Comment: Cool ... I think @JakeLin has some good comments ... I was going to add something like that, but felt odd taking another idea.  You might want to consider always using the braces, in practice.  This will ensure you don't missing anything or do anything unexpected.

Comment: I actually started out using the braces, but when I found that it worked without I started doing that instead. But now I will make a point of using the braces, no matter what, and make it a habit. Again: thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to access the element:

```
if(document.characterform.radio11.checked) //this assumes a form element named: radio11
```

So, in addittion to the brackets, you should check that this way:

```
if(document.getElementById('radio11').checked){ ... } //this assumes a form element with id: radio 11
```

Comment: It works now, with my document.characterform.radio11. But you're saying that still isn't right? If so, I will change it. Just trying to figure out why.

Comment: The structure `document.form.elementform` is to acces the element via name attribute: `<input name="myInput" />`. The structure `document.getElementById('element')` is to acces the element via id attribute: `<input id="myInput" />`. If you're saying that the name-structure is accesing the element, then either your **HTML** code is different than the one you have here and you actually have this: `<input type="radio" name="radio11" value="" id="radio11" />` or javascript has complete changed since the last time I checked (it could be, I'm not a big fan).

Comment: Then javascript must have changed, because the HTML code is the same. But if your way still is best practice I will start using that in stead if it works. Thank you for explaining it to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic should be similar to this. Please bear in mind, if you want to change multiple variables in one block, need to use curly brackets to wrap them together.

```
if(document.getElementById('radio11').checked) {
    cartman += 5;
}
else if(document.getElementById('radio12').checked) {
    kyle += 5;
}
else if(document.getElementById('radio13').checked) {
    stan += 5;
}
else if(document.getElementById('radio14').checked) {
    kenny += 5;
}
else if(document.getElementById('radio15').checked) {
    butters += 5;
}
```

Comment: I see your point. But I wanted to make it so that some answers will add points to some characters and take points from others. Also, I'm trying to make it so that you don't end up getting the same amount of points for two characters at the end.

Comment: Just wrap one execution logic within curly brackets, the should do the trick for you.